# Why does the Tango Camera Interface have two separate update texture functions?

Tags: google-project-tango

I am using the lastest Tango release at the time of this question which is Zaniah (Version 1.46, November 2016). I have two devices, a Project Tango development kit and a pre-release Lenovo phone.

Does anyone know why `TangoService_updateTexture` only works when a texture with the target `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` is connected to the camera interface ?

There is a separate `TangoService_updateTextureExternalOes` function which is stated for use with `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`  textures so this gives the impression that `TangoService_updateTexture`  should work with other types of textures such as `GL_TEXTURE_2D` (why else have a separate function?). However if you connect a texture with the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` target then a gl error is generated stating the texture can't be bound when `TangoService_updateTexture` is called, now without seeing the code I'm guessing that the Tango API tries to bind a texture to the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` target regardless of which function is called.

So if this is the case why are there two separate functions ?﻿

Has anybody else observed this, is this intended behaviour or is this a known issue ?

I'm struggling to find any sort of information or documentation about it.

The API docs: https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `TangoService_updateTexture` and `TangoService_updateTextureExternalOes` uses OES texture. Unfortunately, Tango only supports OES texture through C-API functions.

The major difference between these two functions is that `TangoService_updateTexture` requires `TangoService_connectTexture` with a valid texture id beforehand. That means when calling `TangoService_connectTexture` you have to have a valid texture id (and of course, a gl-context) setup. This ties gl-context's lifecycle very tightly together with Tango&Android lifecycle. This can be a little bit tricky to handle in some cases.

On the other side, `TangoService_updateTextureExternalOes` doesn't require any texture id setup before calling this function, so you can simply call it in `render()` function, which guarantees that gl-context is available.